# pq a função somar esta sendo interpretada antes da sua declaração do escopo?

Tags: javascript

Ao ficar testando alguns recursos do JavaScript no aprendizado me deparei com o seguinte problema, ao executar esse código não consegui entender o porque da função somar não disparar um error sendo que ela só foi declarada bem depois de ser chamada no código.

```
console.log(somar(5,5))        //<--copila
console.log(mult(5,5))         //<--nao copila

function somar(x,y){
   return x +y
}

const mult = function (x,y) {
   return x * y
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essa "ordem lógica" não faz diferença para o Javascript devido ao comportamento de **[Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossario/Hoisting)** da linguagem que permite chamar uma variável ou função antes de declará-la.

*Porém*, o seu problema é que estás chamando uma *const* antes mesmo de inicializá-la e o Javascript não permite. Uma *const*, primeiro você *inicializa* e depois *acessa*.
 Basta inverter a ordem, acessando a const após a sua declaração:

```js
    const mult = function (x,y) {
       return x * y
    }

    console.log(mult(5,5))
```

Answer (score 2):

você está declarando "mult" como const e deve ser uma function para que receba os parâmetros. Declare-a como a function somar

```
console.log(somar(5,5))        
console.log(mult(5,5))

 function somar(x,y){
   return x +y
}

function mult(x,y) {
   return x * y
}
```

Comment: Então, oq eu fiz foi definir uma const chamada mult e atribuir a ela uma funcao anonima só que tudo isso ocorreu bem depois de chamar-la por isso ocorreu o error, porem fiz o msm com a funcao soma e esse error n apareceu, foi isso q n conseguir enteder ;s